# Running a main application inside of a play app

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a play app that I run in sbt with the run command.

I created a main function inside of this same app just to test things out, how can I execute the main app in sbt?

If I type run it still as usual starts my play app.

```
package com.blank

object Blah {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("blah!")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `runMain` with your main class, like:

```
sbt "runMain com.blank.Balh"
```